# How do i pass serialize data by PHP in mysql and unserialize to jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Database

```
**username**
admin

**ref**
a:2:{i:0;s:5:"Facebook";i:1;s:6:"Forum";}
```

PHP

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin'";
echo json_encode($query);
```

how can i unserialize Ref and pass to echo json_encode($query); ?

Comment: Hi, this is extremely basic and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. There are plenty of tutorials available for basic database operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='admin'";

$rec    =   mysqli_query($query);
$row    =   mysql_fetch_assoc($rec);

$ref    =   unserialize($row['ref']);

$row['ref'] =   $ref;

echo json_encode($row);
```

Or you can do it like this too

```
$data   =   array();
$data['admin']  =   $row['admin'];
$data['ref']    =   unserialize($row['ref']);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: how i want to pass both admin and ref.

Comment: @user1578359 see the edited answer. after unserialing pass it to the same key of array or create a new array and pass both columns to them

Comment: @user1578359 when you find a solution that fits you need you should accept it. That will increase your reputation and you will gein other benefits at community.